# bibtex apacite problem

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I have a problem with bibtex: it doesn't seem to find my references from my .bib-file.

The Errors I get:

```
[BibTeX] mit Rückgabewert 2 beendet
```

and:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Murty2010' undefined on input line 109.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

My file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
blabliblu\cite{Murty2010}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{library.bib}
\end{document}
```

And my library.bib looks like this:

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley 1.8.5
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

@article{Murty2010,
abstract = {Over the past decade, fMRI techniques have been increasingly 
used to interrogate the neural correlates of successful emotional memory 
encoding. These investigations have typically aimed to either characterize 
the contributions of the amygdala and medial temporal lobe (MTL) memory 
system, replicating results in animals, or delineate the neural correlates 
of specific behavioral phenomena. It has remained difficult, however, to 
synthesize these findings into a systems neuroscience account of how 
networks across the whole-brain support the enhancing effects of emotion on 
memory encoding. To this end, the present study employed a meta-analytic 
approach using activation likelihood estimates to assess the anatomical 
specificity and reliability of event-related fMRI activations related to 
successful memory encoding for emotional versus neutral information. The 
meta-analysis revealed consistent clusters within bilateral amygdala, 
anterior hippocampus, anterior and posterior parahippocampal gyrus, the 
ventral visual stream, left lateral prefrontal cortex and right ventral 
parietal cortex. The results within the amygdala and MTL support a wealth 
of findings from the animal literature linking these regions to arousal-
mediated memory effects. The consistency of findings in cortical targets, 
including the visual, prefrontal, and parietal cortices, underscores the 
importance of generating hypotheses regarding their participation in 
emotional memory formation. In particular, we propose that the amygdala 
interacts with these structures to promote enhancements in perceptual 
processing, semantic elaboration, and attention, which serve to benefit 
subsequent memory for emotional material. These findings may motivate 
future research on emotional modulation of widespread neural systems and 
the implications of this modulation for cognition.},

author = {Murty, Vishnu P and Ritchey, Maureen and Adcock, R Alison and 
LaBar, Kevin S},
doi = {10.1016/j.neuropsychologia.2010.07.030},
file = {:home/alarith/Dokumente/artikel/Murty et al. - 2010.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1873-3514},
journal = {Neuropsychologia},
keywords = {Brain,Brain Mapping,Brain: blood supply,Brain: 
physiology,Emotions,Emotions: physiology,Female,Functional 
Laterality,Functional Laterality: physiology,Humans,Image Processing, 
Computer-Assisted,Image Processing, Computer-Assisted: methods,Magnetic 
Resonance Imaging,Male,Memory,Memory: physiology,Meta-Analysis as 
Topic,Neuropsychological Tests,Oxygen,Oxygen: blood,Photic 
Stimulation,Photic Stimulation: methods},
month = oct,
number = {12},
pages = {3459--69},
pmid = {20688087},
title = {{fMRI studies of successful emotional memory encoding: A 
quantitative meta-analysis.}},
url = {http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/articlerender.fcgi?artid=2949536\&
tool=pmcentrez\&rendertype=abstract},
volume = {48},
year = {2010}
}
@article{Fukuda2010,
...
}
```

I'm using Kile on a Kubuntu 12.04 system with apacite installed. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I actually just derived a workaround myself: In the bibtex output I saw that bibtex can't find an "apacite.bst"-file. so I copied it from my package directory to the working directory with the .tex-file and now it works :-)

Comment: The command `\bibliography` requires the filename without extension.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\bibliography` has one mandatory argument and this is the filename without the extension. So your example works fine when you change

```
\bibliography{library.bib}
```

to

```
\bibliography{library}
```